# Is this definition of an inverse function correct?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, the following definition of an inverse function is given (pg 44.):

> $F^{-1} = \{\langle u,v \rangle | vFu \}$

This doesn't seem correct to me.  The function $F = \{\langle 1, 2 \rangle, \langle 2, 2 \rangle\}$ is a simple example where this does not hold, since $F^{-1} = \{\langle 2, 1 \rangle, \langle 2, 2 \rangle\}$ and this is clearly not a function.

I believe the definition should at the very least state that F must be injective, as this would ensure that $F^{-1}$ actually is a function. But I believe the consensus definition is that an inverse function must also be bijective.

Comment: The paragraph before says "The following operations are most commonly applied to functions, sometimes are applied to relations, but can actually be defined for arbitrary sets A, F, and G." See https://books.google.com/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA35&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @JohnDouma, I totally glazed over this paragraph, now it makes more sense. I guess he is defining a more general "inverse" for any relation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the author should have prefaced the definition with "if it exists"...  or else called it just the inverse *relation* (or maybe that's what was meant).

Secondly, I guess you're right:   if the inverse exists (as a function) we have a bijection...

Otherwise the definition is correct...